# How to parse the message to get sender phone number and text message in a C program?

Tags: c, parsing, at-command

Here is response of the AT command I want to read only phone number and text message? How can I code for this?

```
+CMGR: "REC READ","+18142150657","Joseph cell","11/02/24,19:53:35-20",145,4,0,0,"+13123149621",145,9
Message 1

OK
```

Here's what they said "Get ready here we come"

```
+CMGR: "REC READ","+18145806808","Google voice","11/02/25,23:44:56-20",145,4,0,0,"+13123149621",145,46


OK
```

This is from marys phone

```
+CMGR: "REC READ","+18140521232","Mary cell","11/02/25,21:34:00-20",145,4,0,0,"+13123149621",145,24


OK

ERROR
```

Comment: Can you format the question and provide more details?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to provide alternative solution, solving some issues that are not evaluated in the other answers.

- The number has to be stored as a string (since '+' char is part of it)
- Parsering an AT command response is not so easy as one could expect, since within double quotes comas are allowed (e.g in the phonebook name we could have something like `"Smith, John"`

Before including code of my simple parsering solution, let's do some assumptions:

1. It is an implementation **without `sscanf()`**. I think it will be useful in order to show explicit parsing logic
2. It is an implementation tailored on requirements needs. Since only phone number is relevant for us, we can afford discarding all the remaining part of the main response
3. Maximum phone number length is 20 (indeed *19+1*)
4. Maximum SMS length is 200 (indeed *199+1*)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUM_LEN 20
#define MAX_SMS_LEN 200

int main( void )
{
  char number[MAX_NUM_LEN];
  char text[MAX_SMS_LEN];

  char exampleCGMRResponse[] = "+CMGR: \"REC READ\",\"+18142150657\",\"Joseph cell\",\"11/02/24,19:53:35-20\",145,4,0,0,\"+13123149621\",145,9\r\nMessage 1\r\n\r\nOK";
  char *pTmp;

  memset(number, 0, sizeof(number));
  memset(text, 0, sizeof(text));

  /* Get phone number */
  pTmp = strstr( exampleCGMRResponse, "+CMGR: \"REC READ\",\"" );
  if( pTmp )
  {
    strncpy( number, pTmp + strlen("+CMGR: \"REC READ\",\""), MAX_NUM_LEN-1 );

    /* Search closing double quote and cut the string where it's found */
    for( pTmp=number; *pTmp != '\0'; pTmp++  )
    {
      if(*pTmp == '"')
      {
        *pTmp = '\0';
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Get SMS Text. Starting after first \r\n */
  pTmp = strstr( exampleCGMRResponse, "\r\n" );
  if( pTmp )
  {
    strncpy( text, pTmp + strlen("\r\n"), MAX_SMS_LEN-1 );

    /* Search closing string "\r\n\r\nOK" */
    pTmp = strstr( text, "\r\n\r\nOK" );
    if( pTmp )
    {
      *pTmp = '\0';
    }
  }

  printf( "Message sender number is \"%s\"\n", number );
  printf( "Message text is \"%s\"\n", text );
  
  return 0;
}
```

As you might notice:

1. Data section of the command is searched after first `\r\n` pattern. In fact, by AT commands standard, the main response cannot contain that pattern
2. AT commands responses data sections are **always** closed by `\r\n\r\nOK` pattern.

Improvements left to the implementations of the asker (in order to simplify my answer):

1. `\r\n\r\nOK` pattern should be searched starting *from the end* of the response
2. A preliminary filter can be done on **status** parameter of `+CGMR` response, in this example hardcoded to `"\"REC READ\""`. It can have also values `"\"REC UNREAD\""`, `"\"STO SENT\""` and `"\"STO UNSENT\""`.

The output of this implementation is

> Message sender number is "+18142150657"
>
> Message text is "Message 1"

Answer (score 1):

Parse line by line using *sscanf*

Something like this for the number:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 // ...

 // Do this for each line
 size_t num;
 sscanf( line_string, "+CMGR: \"REC READ\",\"+%lu\",", &num);
```

Comment: Would you really store a phone number as a long integer? A phone number is a string, and `+` is part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Some general considerations

1. You can store the phone number in a char array. This can have a size of 20 to store all possible cases.
2. The message is stored in another char array. The max size needs to be determined from the manual of your GMS module. I have assumed this as 200.
3. The input data is read into a char array. The conversion function below is called after checking for Error
4. The conversion function can return a boolean to inform whether the conversion is successful.
5. Assumption that the input string will always have same format (i.e. number of commas) spaces etc.
6. You can then do tokenization using `strtok` based on the `,` and then strip the starting and ending `"`
7. To get the message tokenize upto the last `,`. Then read the length of the message and also the entire message

Here below is a general idea of how to carry this out for the phone number

```
typedef struct 
{
    char number[20];
    char message[200];
    // Add here for other fields.
} MessageType;


bool ParseMessage (char * input, MessageType *pOutput)
{
    char *tok;
    int parametercount = 0,len;

    tok = strtok(input, ",");
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        switch (parametercount)
        {
            case 2: //number 
                len = strlen(tok);
                if (len >= 9) // can check for minimum number size
                {
                    strcpy(pOutput->number,tok+1);
                    // delete the last `"`
                    if (pOutput->number[len-1] == '"')
                    {
                        pOutput->number[len-1] = '\0';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                break;
             default:
                break;
        }
        parametercount++;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    if (paremetercount == 10)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```